# Как принять файл отправленный через ajax в flask?

Tags: python, html, ajax, flask

Отправляю файл с помощью такого кода:
let input_file = document.getElementById('input-file')

```
input_file.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
let file = e.target.files[0];

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/post/file',
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentData: false,
    data: {
         'file': file
    },
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    }
})
```

А на сервере пытаюсь получать файл так:

```
@posts.route('/post/file', methods=['POST'])
def download_file():
    file = request.files['file']
```

Вылазит такая ошибка:

```
KeyError: 'file'
```

Comment: А вы смотрели в браузерном мониторинге сети, отправляется ли файл вообще?

Comment: @andreymal да отправляется

Answer (score 0):

во фласке я не силен, но когда-то я делал так.

```
@app.route('/post/file', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download_file():
    file = request.files.get('file')
    file.save('./' + file.filename)
```

пришлось залезть в этот учебник "Flask Web development" и по нему программировать. не знаю, правильно получилось или нет.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3 
import os
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, url_for, abort
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 1024 * 1024
app.config['UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS'] = ['.jpg', '.png', '.gif']
app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'] = 'uploads'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_files():
    uploaded_file = request.files['file']
    filename = secure_filename(uploaded_file.filename)
    if filename != '':
        file_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
        if file_ext not in app.config['UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS']:
            abort(400)
        uploaded_file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'], filename))
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: Это логически то же самое, что написано у автора вопроса. Только в данном случае из-за использования get вместо ошибки KeyError будет ошибка `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filename'`